# Dynamic Template in Component Angular 6

Tags: angular, ng-template

I am new to Angular, so I am sorry if I screw up the jargon.
I am trying to dynamically use templateURL (html) in my component, the Class function will remain the same but html will change depending on `binType`

This is my component class source

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, Output, EventEmitter, AfterViewInit, ViewContainerRef, ViewChild, Compiler, Injector, NgModule, NgModuleRef } from '@angular/core';

declare var module: {
  id: string;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-cart-bin',
  styleUrls: ['./cart-bin.component.css'],  
  template: ` 
      <ng-template #dynamicTemplate></ng-template>
    `

})

export class CartBinComponent implements AfterViewInit, OnInit {

  @ViewChild('dynamicTemplate', {read: ViewContainerRef}) dynamicTemplate;


  public cols = 3;
  public rows = 3;

  @Input() binType = "";

  @Input() toteList = [];

  @Output() callbackMethod = new EventEmitter<string>();

  constructor(private _compiler: Compiler, private _injector: Injector, private _m: NgModuleRef<any>) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.binType);
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {

    let tmpObj;

    console.log(tmpObj);

    if ((this.binType) == "2") {
      tmpObj = {
        moduleId: module.id,
        templateUrl : './cart-bin.component_02.html'
      };
    } else {
      tmpObj = {
        moduleId: module.id,
        templateUrl : './cart-bin.component_01.html'
      };
    }

    console.log(tmpObj);

    const tmpCmp = Component(tmpObj)(class {});

    const tmpModule = NgModule({declarations: [tmpCmp]})(class {});

    this._compiler.compileModuleAndAllComponentsAsync(tmpModule).then((factories) => {
      const f = factories.componentFactories[0];
      const cmpRef = f.create(this._injector, [], null, this._m);
      cmpRef.instance.name = 'dynamic';
      this.dynamicTemplate.insert(cmpRef.hostView);
    });
}

  getToteBoxClass(toteData){
    ...
  } 

  getToteIcon(toteData){
    ...
  }

  toteSaveClick(toteData){
    ...
  }
}
```

This is compiling but template is not parsing and getting the following error

```
ERROR Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'ngStyle' since it isn't a known property of 'div'.
```

Html is correct I used it directly as part of @Component TypeDecorator

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Besides the fact that using the compiler and creating dynamic components is pretty anti pattern in angular, I believe you can fix your error by adding the `CommonModule` to your NgModule declaration:

```
NgModule({imports: [CommonModule], declarations: [tmpCmp]})
```

Better would be though to use an [`ngSwitchCase`](https://angular.io/api/common/NgSwitchCase) in your template, create two components which inherit from a base component but have different templates, and depending on the `binType` let it render one or the other component:

template:

```
<ng-container [ngSwitch]="binType">
  <cart-bin-1 *ngSwitchCase="1"></cart-bin-1>
  <cart-bin-2 *ngSwitchCase="2"></cart-bin-2>
</ng-container>
```

ts:

```
export abstract class CartBin {
  // some common cart bin logic here:
}


@Component({
  selector: 'cart-bin-1',
  templateUrl: './cart-bin.component_01.html' 
})
export class CartBin1 extends CartBin {

}

@Component({
  selector: 'cart-bin-2',
  templateUrl: './cart-bin.component_02.html' 
})
export class CartBin2 extends CartBin  {

}
```

The advantage of using this, is that the AOT bundle will not include the compiler anymore, and therefor making your application smaller and faster. Also, this looks much better :)

Comment: Thank You, I used the ngSwitchCase. And it works.
 
I'm sorry but could you explain this a bit 
`Besides the fact that using the compiler and creating dynamic components is pretty anti pattern`

Comment: @MediocreDev 99.99% of the time while using angular there is no need of using the `Compiler` class. Especially when you are 'new' to angular, and you find yourself thinking that you should use it, correct yourself and tell yourself that there is a better way which you do not know yet :) For instance now with the ngwitchCae

Comment: In above code snippet, html is there in file. But what if that html is coming from some server and have custom directive in it ? What is the best approach ?

Comment: @Prashanth in that case you are not using angular the right way :) because that html needs to be dynamically compiled. If it's possible you can change your build process to build the application while getting the html files from the server. If that's not possible, you should not use angular this way. Dynamic templates should be achieved using the built-in directives like ngSwitchCase ngIf etc.

Comment: @PierreDuc My question was in the context of modernizing the legacy and old application UI with Angular 6 while keeping the legacy back end architecture and code intact where in we get html ( from DB via back end requests ) with tags having custom attribute containing the image id which needs to queried from front end and display html with image as a component.

Comment: @PierreDuc Using switch case is not really a solution here. 
Please check this discussion. https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/15275
What if I have 100 bins? Should I create this huge switch? And if I have 1000 - switch as well? Clearly not. So you r saying final answer here is "this is not task for angular"?

Comment: @azrahel it all depends on your current case. This question was somebody who was new to angular and using the wrong things for the wrong tasks. I believe every specific use case has their own solution in angular. If you have a 1000 different options, you can try to use a Map object which contains the components you want to use, in combination with the ngComponentOutlet you can go a long way

Comment: @PierreDuc ok, I understand your point. Do you think map solution is better than switch? You will still have this giant map object somewhere in code. Giant switch or giant map, is there any difference?

Comment: @azrahel parse time will be quicker with just a map. And you can organize this map in a single file. You can even split it up in categories, and use the `...` spread operator to merge it in a single object. Doing this in the template is a bit dirty